# How to fix NPCs not spawning

Tags: lua, roblox

I coded out some functions in a ModuleScript to be executed by another script. Here is the code

```
local module = {}

wavepause = game.ReplicatedStorage.Values.WavePauseLength.Value
trollanoid = game.ReplicatedStorage.Trollanoid
spawnpoints = workspace.Test1.Spawns:GetChildren()

function trollanoidsummon()
    local chosenspawn = math.random(#spawnpoints)
    local clone = trollanoid:Clone().Parent == workspace.Zombies
    clone.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = chosenspawn.CFrame
end

module.Wave1 = function()
    trollanoid()
    wait(1)
    trollanoid()
    wait(1)
    trollanoid()
    wait(1)
    trollanoid()
end

return module
```

What I expected was the NPC trollanoids to appear on the map,  but instead I got this error in the output:

```
17:50:19.011  ServerScriptService.WaveModule:14: attempt to call a Instance 
value  -  Server  -  WaveModule:14
```

I dont know what I did wrong, please help me fix this. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you what's wrong:

You're trying to [call](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.10) an object. The only things you can call in Lua are *functions* and objects with the `__call` metamethod.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling an object. Like mentioned above, you can only call functions and objects with __call metamethod.

Try this:

```lua
local module = {}

wavepause = game.ReplicatedStorage.Values.WavePauseLength
trollanoid = game.ReplicatedStorage.Trollanoid
spawnpoints = workspace.Test1.Spawns:GetChildren()

function trollanoidsummon()
    local chosenspawn = spawnpoints[math.random(#spawnpoints)]
    local clone = trollanoid:Clone().Parent = workspace.Zombies
    clone.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = chosenspawn.CFrame
end

module:SpawnNPC(amount, threshold)
    threshold = threshold or 1
    amount = amount or 4
    for i = 1, amount do
        if wavepause.Value then break end;
        trollanoidsummon()
        wait(threshold)
    end
end

return module
```

To use the module you would do this:

```lua
local spawner = require(modulescriptpath);
spawner:SpawnNPC(5, 1);
```

I made a few minor changes. Let me know if you need help with any :)