# Attempt to index boolean with HumanoidRootPart

Tags: lua, roblox

I put in these lines of code in a module script I made for my zombie game, specifically to put in wave structures featuring different zombies each wave:

```
local module = {}

wavepause = game.ReplicatedStorage.Values.WavePauseLength.Value
trollanoid = game.ReplicatedStorage.Trollanoid
spawnpoints = workspace.Test1.Spawns:GetChildren()

function trollanoidsummon()
    local chosenspawn = spawnpoints[math.random(#spawnpoints)]
    local clone = trollanoid:Clone().Parent == workspace.Zombies
    clone.HumanoidRootPart.Position = chosenspawn.Position
end

module.Wave1 = function()
    trollanoidsummon()
    wait(1)
    trollanoidsummon()
    wait(1)
    trollanoidsummon()
    wait(1)
    trollanoidsummon()
end

return module
```

and got this in return:

```
 22:00:27.837  ServerScriptService.WaveModule:10: attempt to index boolean with 
'HumanoidRootPart'  -  Server  -  WaveModule:10
```

How to fix?

Comment: `clone` is boolean.  What should it be instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix NPCs not spawning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65436688/how-to-fix-npcs-not-spawning)

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator is a question: "are these two things equal?"

The line `local clone = trollanoid:Clone().Parent == workspace.Zombies` is asking the question, "is this cloned trollanoid in the zombies folder in the workspace?" and saving the answer in the `cloned` variable.

Clone the object, add it to the world, and store the clone into a variable... You are trying to do too many things in a single line. To fix your problem, just space out your code.

```
function trollanoidsummon()
    local chosenspawn = spawnpoints[math.random(#spawnpoints)]
    local clone = trollanoid:Clone()
    clone.Parent = workspace.Zombies
    clone.HumanoidRootPart.Position = chosenspawn.Position
end
```